# In Emacs dired, how do I select files based on names from a list?

Tags: emacs, dired

I open a buffer in emacs dired and select some files.  How would I go about selecting files with the **same name** in **another buffer**?  Ex: I select files a.txt, k.txt and z.txt in folder A.  I then open a folder B in dired...how could I mark the files with the same names in folder B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following elisp code worked for me with buffers `dired1` and `dired2`.

```lisp
(progn
  (switch-to-buffer "dired1")
  (dlet ((files (mapcar (lambda (path) (car (last (split-string path "/"))))
                        (dired-get-marked-files))))
    (switch-to-buffer "dired2")
    (dired-mark-sexp '(member name files))))
```

Comment: Wooowww, that works.  Sorry for the newbie question, is there a way to wrap this so that I could invoke it with a M-x something?  Thanks a lot anyhow :-)

Comment: You need to replace the `progn` by a `defun`, replace direds by variables and somehow populate them from `interactive`. The last step is to `global-set-key`. Most of it should be available here or on https://emacs.stackexchange.com.